# Eclipse type / import error with built java file

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, types, build

I have a project where we use a ant buildfile to create some .java files. Those built files need to reference to already existing other java files.
My problem is that the built file can have a code line as for example

```
arg = (Expr) new Ast.BinaryOP(lhs, BOp.B_MINUS, rhs);
```

where it will show an error "Ast.BinaryOP cannot be resolved to a type". I then can type Ast.BinaryOP again and use autocomplete to pick the BinaryOP part and the error will disappear. The same with BOp.B_MINUS.
I did import (probably way too many times) the necessary other files as far as I can tell.
I.e.

```
import cd.ir.Ast;
import cd.ir.Ast.*;
import cd.ir.Ast.Expr;
import cd.ir.Ast.BinaryOp;
import cd.ir.Ast.BinaryOp.BOp;
```

So far I tried

- restarting Eclipse
- 'clean' the project
- to just run the project anyway (doesn't work)
- remove the "Ast." part which will work once again if I do it in Eclipse but not if generated that way
- Google the problem, respectively search it on Stackoverflow which turned out to be hard as there are many related issues. There are no good keywords as far as I can tell.
- deleted the project from Eclipse and imported it newly

I need to repeatedly run the ant build file to test the code from where the .java file is generated, thus changing all errors manually is not an option.

Thanks for any advice/help in advance. I will gladly provide more information if you tell me what could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting with a friend who didn't see the issue either I finally found it. So logical in retrospect but small enough that I spend 2,5h trying to find it:

```
import cd.ir.Ast.BinaryOp;
```

vs:

```
new Ast.BinaryOP(....
```

BinaryO**p** vs. BinaryO**P**

Answer (score 1):

Hit F5 on the project, open the file, and then try hitting Ctrl+Shift+O to automatically organize the imports.

Comment: I always refresh the project before and after running the Ant. That doesn't change anything (edit: I mean it does change something ofc, but doesn't resolve the issue).
Organizing the imports does nothing to resolve the problem either. I can have `new Ast.BinaryOP(....)` written and it will suggest to change it to `new BinaryOP(....)`. 10 lines below I have `new BinaryOP(.....)` and it will tell me that BinaryOP cannot be resolved as a type.

Comment: Oh my god, it was just a typo ? Worst thing is that I saw it, but thought it was just a typo in the post !